# Getting a lot of timeouts on multi threaded database connections

Tags: c#, multithreading, postgresql

I have a program that runs a series of commands to the same server on 5 different databases. It is threaded and each thread creates a new connection, runs query and puts results in a thread safe collection which is pulled from by another application. This program works and does everything it is meant to, but I get a lot of connection time-outs.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(NodeList, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15, CancellationToken = CancelToken.Token }, node => {
        using (CancellationTokenSource cancel = CancelToken.Token.CreateLinkedSource()) {
            while (true) {
                node.Attempts++;
                try {
                    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(node.ConnectionString)) {
                        conn.Open();
                        using (NpgsqlCommand npgQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(node.Query, conn)) {
                            cancel.Token.Register(() => {
                                npgQuery.Cancel();
                            });
                            npgQuery.Prepare();
                            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgQuery.ExecuteReader()) {
                                while (reader.Read()) {
                                    Row row = new Row();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                                        row.AddColumn(reader.GetName(i), reader.GetFieldType(i), reader.GetValue(i));
                                    }
                                    Producer.Add(row);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (node.Attempts >= RetryAttempts) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the guts of my threaded connection download. Each Node instance has a connection string which specifies that Pooling=false and a query, which is irrelevant.

The database has a connection limit of 200 and I have never seen it get above 30 so that is not the issue.

If I add:

```
Thread.Sleep(random.Next(50, 1500));
```

To the start of each thread I get less timeouts so I get the feeling it's a timing issue with establishing connections, but this is unreliable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Increase connection timeout value. There was an issue with ADO.NET that Microsoft acknowledged. Not sure that is the case for you but you can try. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2011/05/25/ado-net-application-connecting-to-a-mirrored-sql-server-database-may-timeout-long-before-the-actual-connection-timeout-elapses-sometimes-within-milliseconds/

Comment: I have the connection timeout at 30 seconds which should be plenty. I just ran it with a connection timeout of 180 seconds and had the same issue. Also if I run these connections synchronously they never timeout, so I don't think this will be the issue.